# How to properly setup accepts_nested_attributes_for in belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following tables:

[image]

models:

```
class Pageview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :visitor
end

class Visitor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pageviews
end
```

and I would like to know how to properly setup the pageview model and pageviews controller so I can create a visitor from the `PageviewsController#create` controller. Right now it works for the common columns:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class PageviewsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @pageview = Pageview.new(pageview_params)

    if @pageview.save
      render json: @pageview, status: :created
    else
      render json: @pageview.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # private

  def pageview_params
    params.require(:pageview).permit(:visitor_id, :is_bounce, :duration, :render_time, :ttfb, :visitor_attributes)
  end
end
```

and I can call the endpoint passing:

```
{
  "pageview": {
    // valid columns
  }
}
```

What I would like to do know is setup things so I can pass an array of visitors:

```
{
  "pageview": {
    // valid columns
    "visitors": [...]
  }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In the strong parameters for your `page_views` controller, `visitor_attributes` has to be an array like this `... :ttfb, visitor_atttributes: [:ip_address, :request_referrer]`
There's a little more to it also You might wanna watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jc4oJY_voHE

Here's the link to the Rails docs about this feature: [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)